# Where's the most efficient place to store my items in Proudspire Manor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In my Whiterun house, the bottom floor is full of chests and storage areas, and my Alchemy table has a satchel for me to keep ingredients in.

I just bought a Solitude house and fully upgraded it, and I'm really surprised at the lack of storage space. There's no alchemy satchel that I can see, and there don't appear to be ANY chests on the bottom floor, so storing alchemy/enchanting reagents is going to be a pain in the ass.

Am I missing something? Where's the most efficient place to store my items in Proudspire Manor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only containers in the basement of Proudspire manor are the barrels in the back room with the cot and the barrel next to the weapon rack.

I believe this is a house mostly for displaying stuff with multiple weapon plaques, mannequins, and weapon racks, and lots of book shelves. Functionality wise its not the best.

However, its the only house with a safe as a container in the main bedroom.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to value having a safe as a container in the house/ AFAIK, safes don't have any more value to the player than any other container.

Comment: @Iszi you are arguing about aesthetics in a game where one of the goals is to spend hundreds of hours collecting materials to build your own house?

Comment: Not meant to be arguing - I was just curious if there was something I'd missed.

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom floor (the one where you enter from without going up the stairs outside) there are 6 places where i keep my items. First as soon as you enter, on your right, there are **2 barrels** and **THREE sacks** in the top left of the room above a box. Then if you walk down further, there is a **3rd barrel** near the enchanting table and weapon racks.

For me this is plenty, i keep my weapons in the weapon rack barrel. The stuff i want to sell in the first barrel. My clothes in the 2nd barrel. Alchemy ingredients in sack 1, soul gems and gems in sack 2, and dragon bones/scales in 3rd barrel (cause i hoard them :P).

I also keep jewelry in the safe and random junk in the chest in the bedroom. Mannequin 1 has daedric armor and mannequin 2 has thalmor hooded robes. A bunch of food in the sack near the kitchen and books on all the shelves and weapons on the racks lol. In case you couldn't tell, i love Proudspire Manor XD.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem so I spawned a couple npcs then killed them and use their bodies for storage.  I haven't had any problems yet with their bodies disapearing.  If you're playing on a console you could kill a follower and use their body.

Comment: Dead bodies in a home *will* despawn eventually. I know this because my Riften housecarl went homicidal on me when I came home one day.

Comment: Well I better get my stuff out of those bodies then.  I have looked through a bunch of item codes but I haven't found one to spawn a chest.  I might have to download a mod to meet my storage requirements.

Comment: You could always just... y'know, store stuff upstairs. Or move into a different house.